# Dividing and multiplying Decimal objects in Python

Tags: python, computer-science, floating-accuracy

In the following code, both coeff1 and coeff2 are Decimal objects. When i check their type using type(coeff1), i get (class 'decimal.Decimal')  but when i made a test code and checked decimal objects i get decimal. Decimal, without the word class

```
coeff1 = system[i].normal_vector.coordinates[i]
coeff2 = system[m].normal_vector.coordinates[i]
x = coeff2/coeff1
print(type(x))
system.xrow_add_to_row(x,i,m)
```

another issue is when i change the first input to the function xrow_add_to_row to negative x:

```
system.xrow_add_to_row(-x,i,m)
```

I get invalid operation error at a line that is **above** the changed code:

```
<ipython-input-11-ce84b250bafa> in compute_triangular_form(self)
     93             coeff1 = system[i].normal_vector.coordinates[i]
     94             coeff2 = system[m].normal_vector.coordinates[i]
---> 95             x = coeff2/coeff1
     96             print(type(coeff1))
     97             system.xrow_add_to_row(-x,i,m)

InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionUndefined'>]
```

But then again in a test code i use negative numbers with Decimal objects and it works fine. Any idea what the problem might be? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

`decimal.DivisionUndefined` is raised when you attempt to divide zero by zero. It's a bit confusing as you get a different exception when only the divisor is zero (`decimal.DivisionByZero`)

```
>>> import decimal.Decimal as D
>>> D(0) / D(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    D(0) / D(0)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionUndefined'>]
>>> D(1) / D(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    D(1) / D(0)
decimal.DivisionByZero: [<class 'decimal.DivisionByZero'>]
```